# Javascript / Nodejs use await on top level in nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I tried finding the solution to my problem, but couldnt find it, and was looking for some "best practice examples". I have a nodejs express application and my functions are split in files. For example I have this controller (oktacontroller.js):

```
var okta_api_key = <here some await data, getting from db>;

const OKTA_ORG_URL = '<here too>';

exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {

    console.log(okta_api_key);
}

exports.getGroups = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(okta_api_key);
}
```

In both exported functions (which are express routes) I need the var okta_api_key. I know I can get them by querying them in both functions, because they are async functions and I can use await there, but it feels dumb to query this every time (because it wont ever change).

How can I manage this? I know I can do this:

```js
var okta_api_key;
(async () => {
    okta_api_key = await <getting key async>
})()
```

But this feels off as well..

Is there any way too make some sort of large function, which is async, and exports the two functions? In other words: How do I use await on the top level of a file (module). It doesnt need to be on top level (its impossible), but some sort of method to have my "top level" variables exposed to my exported functions.

EDIT: Some other usecase, because I got the suggestion of putting it in a config file. Yes, for this one it is possible, but for example: I have some other api key which gets his access token from the service itself, on every startup (because it expires). That token cannot be stored in the config file, so I need some async work to get the value. I know top-level-await is not working (or even not desirable), but I just want an example of how you guys would do this if it were your project :)

Comment: Not at present, it's still a [Stage 2 proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-top-level-await/) and I would suggest reading this: [Top-level await is a footgun](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221).

Comment: If it never changes why does it need to be stored in the db? Just put it in a config file and import it into your module.

Comment: Yeah, but I can (and want to) change settings via the GUI (my app)

Comment: Simple. set `var okta_api_key` to a promise, which you can await as many times as you want without actually performing the async task over and over.

Comment: So just say const okta_api_key = doSomethingAsync() and then in the functions say const real_api_key = await okta_api_key()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are close:

```
 var okta_api_key = (async () => {
    return  await <getting key async>
 })();
```

Create a promise, then  `await` that promise whenever you want to use it.

> How do I use await on the top level of a file (module).

Top level `await` might look great: You just add one `await` and then you can access the variable synchronously. But that simplifies things too much: It will stop all modules depending on that module from executing. In most cases you don't want that¹. Instead create a promise of the async task, then await it when needed. That way you limit the asynchronous execution to the code pieces that actually need it.

---

¹ Those rare cases are:

1) Loading some global config, that you have to access everywhere in your code, so it makes no sense to start the service if the config isn't ready.

2) `await`ing in the top level file of your service: As no module depends on it, this won't cause any problems.

---

Side note: Top level await is not yet specified, and the NodeJS support is also not there yet. To use it in production you have to wait a few months (?).

Comment: Thanks, it does seem to work (your example), BUT it returns a Promise <key here>. I just want the string. So, the promise resolved correctly, but okta_api_key doesnt contain the correct value

Comment: BTW, how would you handle this?

Comment: Yes. `await` that promise and everything is fine.

Comment: thats not possible on TL?

Comment: var okta_api_key = (async () => {
    return  await process.env.OKTA_API_KEY;
 })(); doesnt work because in okta_api_key there is Promise <akjhdkajbckjsygdfkjh(real api key)>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: That is a nice piece of text about asynchronous functions in JS, but its not the answer to my question. I want to have a var/const which is filled with async data (so not immediately) to be accessible by 2 functions which are declared later on in the file

Comment: No, you don't want that. Trust me.

Comment: Exactly, so how would you solve this? Thats what I cant find everywhere. TLA is a no-go but I dont get any solutions to my problem. If you have 2 functions which need the same data, what would you do?

Comment: Ah, I think you and Kevin B (replied to the original post) are meaning the same thing, arent you? Then this is the way to go I guess

Comment: Make the functions async, await the promise. And yes, Kevin B says the same.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I marked your reply as an answer, thanks a lot. Makes a lot more sense now.