# using await instead of .then using fetch

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am using a code example I found using fetch, async, await.  I am having trouble figuring out how to substitute a .then in the code for another await.

Here is the code

```
    async function getData(url = "", data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

const response = getData(
  "https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/scoreboard"
).then((data) => {
  console.log(data.leagues[0].name);
});
```

I tried

```
const response =  await getData(
  "https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/scoreboard"
)
```

But got an error `await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

What should I do?

Comment: Please show more context. Where/how are you running this code? Where in your application is the `getData()` called?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089471/async-await-syntaxerror-await-is-only-valid-in-async-functions-and-the-top-le

Answer (score -2):

The answer is on the description. Await is only allowed on an async function. what you can do is transform it on an function:

```js
async function runGetData(){
    const response =  await getData("https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/scoreboard")
    console.log(response)
}

runGetData()
```

If i just want to call `runGetData` without waiting for his response i can. Of couse i would not know when it was done executing without await or then.