# Error node.js application: actions and the top level bodies of modules (at index.js:13:21)

Tags: node.js, async-await

I've learned a lot about it, but I didn't figure it out why I got this error:

```
Only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at index.js:13:21)
```

That's the code:

```
async function run() {
    console.log("running...");


    const config = {
        auth: {
            clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/',
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
    };
    var client = new msal.PublicClientApplication(config);
    
    var loginRequest = {
        scopes: [ 'user.read' ]
    };
    let loginResponse = await client.loginPopup(loginRequest);
    console.log('Login Response', loginResponse);

}
```

The run function is called from front-end page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="run()">
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-inverse fa-play"></i>
       Run Code
</button>
```

Comment: Hello, can you share the main code of the `run()` function call ?

Comment: thank you ! I have two questions: 
- is `run()` function defined in nodeJs environment ? or in a separate frontend script file ? 
- if it is the second case (separate frontend script): did you try to simulate click event with addEventListener instead of using it directly in Html Dom events ? 

PS: remember that your function is defined as `async` function, which means that you have to handle your code with Promises (either by using `await` or `.then( ).catch( )`

Comment: you can also check this [await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089471/async-await-syntaxerror-await-is-only-valid-in-async-functions-and-the-top-le)